# Editing a system preferences .plist file (not user preferences .plist file)

Tags: plist

I'm using an app that has .plist files in the user path ~/Library/Preferences/com.xyz.app.plist and the system path /Library/Preferences/com.xyz.app.plist

From the command line I can edit the user .plist with `defaults write com.xyz.app.plist key value`

But how do I edit the system .plist file from the Command line?

Using "sudo" with the defaults command didn't work. In fact, it didn't seem to have any effect at all.

Editing it in Xcode isn't preferable, but I can't do it there either. Using Xcode, I can bring up the system .plist file. But it's not letting me edit saying it's locked and not letting me unlock in Xcode.

I've also `chmod 666` the system .plist file from 644, with no effect on editing from the command line or Xcode. I've started Xcode under root, and it still had the same issue with the file being locked.

How do I edit this system .plist file (preferably from the command line)?

Comment: The `defaults write...` command you cited *is* editing the file from the command line, so I’m not understanding what you mean by “edit from the command line.”  The fact that it has no effect could mean that whatever you’re writing has no relevance.  For instance, I can issue the command `defaults write com.apple.powersave hamsters bool 1` to turn on the hamster power boost feature, but since it hasn’t been implemented, you’re not going to see anything.

Comment: So....what exactly are you trying to accomplish?  What do you want to edit and why?  What command, exactly, are you issuing?

Comment: I want to edit the system .plist file /Library/Preferences/com.xyz.app.plist, not the user ~/Library/Preferences/com.xyz.app.plist.  `defaults write...` is only editing the user file. The setting I want to edit is unimportant - I just want to be able to make any change to the system .plist file.

Comment: If you’re using catalina, the system volume is read only.  Also, have you looked at the `plutil` utility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defaults` can also work on plist files specified on the command line, so you can use

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/om.xyz.app.plist key value
```

Answer (score 0):

I use BBEdit for modifying plist files in /Library/Preferences, which has the advantage of handling the authorization needed to obtain write permission, and then save the files with their original attributes.

Comment: doesn't work anymore - the system plist files are locked and BBEdit cannot unlock them.

Comment: @zaam It works for me. What's the path of the file you're trying to open?

Comment: Sorry, it unlocks but I can't edit it. I'm trying to change /Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkextension.plist to get rid of a stray VPN entry

Comment: It's to do with SIP. Seems like SIP was blocking all the edits. Fixed it now. Thanks.